# Как сервисы по разгадке капчи получают reCAPTCHA V2?

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

Есть сервисы, которые предоставляют работникам капчу, что бы они её разгадывали, так, вот. Вопрос такой, как только при помощи captchaKey и ссылки на страницу на которой установлена капча, они подгружают капчу? Ведь там же идет проверка домена и по сути пользователям должна показываться надпись что домен не верный.

Comment: Ничто не мешает создать поддельный сайт с нужным доменом, если требуется его работа только на компьютере работника

Comment: @andreymal я пытался подменять  информацию при загрузке капчи, но все равно была ошибка, что домен не верный.

Comment: Как-то неправильно пытались значит

Comment: @andreymal, ну наверное, по этому и задал вопрос, по сути нужно, эту же капчу эмулировать, но на другом сайте. Как. Пока не понимаю.

Comment: Подделать сайт очень элементарно, прописав в системном файле hosts для нужного домена IP-адрес подконтрольного вам сервера (например, вашего собственного же компьютера 127.0.0.1)

Comment: @andreymal Мне это нужно делать на стороне своего сайта. Т.е. условно. Есть сайт blabla.com на нем рекапча, я копирую от туда данные капчи capchaKey, вставляю у себя на сайте. Разгадываю на нем,  (вот тут возникает проблема, капча не проргужается и пишет ошибку домена).